# How can I get my website source code after my friend locked me out?

Tags: iis-7, server

I need to get the source code from my IIS7 webserver. I gave my friend access to the source so he could help with maintenance; however, after a couple months of inactivity, he has locked me out of my own repository and now pays for it himself (I don't know why he did this).

How do I get the source from the webserver? I use IIS7.

Comment: That sucks. You're probably going to be out of luck, you can grab HTML with a scraper, but accessing actual code files is going to be impossible. Do you have FTP access?

Comment: Not anymore - he changed the password for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming issue as defined in the [help] and the answers are at best legal advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two things you could do now:

1. Ask him for the sources
2. Take a lawyer and sue him

Comment: 3. Beat the password out of him with a big stick. ;)

Comment: Would not suggest this. He may choose my solution No 2 against you

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the source code of a server side web app that runs on IIS7 if you only have access to the web app through the web server. This is by design.